# How can I match nothing when there isn't anything between tags?

Tags: php, regex

**I know.** Parsing the HTML by RegEx is a wrong approach. But honestly I have no time to learn using a PHP DOM parser. So please just answer my question.

---

Here is [my current pattern](https://regex101.com/r/qpZk2J/2):

```
<a href="(.*?)"><li>[\s\S]+?<img src="([^"]+)[\s\S]+?<p>([^<]+)[\s\S]+?<s([^>]+)([^<]+)<\/span>
```

It almost works. Just the last capturing group matches `>` of `<span>` tag. While want to match the value of `<span>` tag. How can I do that? *(usually the `<span>` doesn't have any value, so it should match nothing)*

---

Noted that adding `pan>` in the pattern causes *Catastrophic Backtracking* error. I mean this:

```
<a href="(.*?)"><li>[\s\S]+?<img src="([^"]+)[\s\S]+?<p>([^<]+)[\s\S]+?<span>([^>]+)([^<]+)<\/span>
/* ---------------------------- added -----------------------------------^^^^
```

Comment: Downvoted, did you even read my question? Getting a downvote before 10sec after asking is weird. Anyway, please leave a comment and explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: Parsing the HTML by RegEx is the wrong approach. Stop making excuses, and learn how to use a DOM parser.

Comment: Well, what's wrong is that even though you know that regex is wrong approach, you're still trying to do it - with a really complex regex. Sad truth is that learning DOMDocument would take less time to do what you want than finding someone who will fix this expression for you. I didn't downvote you, but it's just not true that finding the "mistake" in your regex will do any good - you missed out on NUMEROUS false positives, and receiving this one fix won't mean it works. You probably got the downvote because someone rolled their eyes when they saw what you're doing and how it's done.

Comment: Also, "I have no time so I want to do it the wrong way even though I can't assert it works" is something no programmer should have in their vocabulary. Good luck with this expression, I hope you get the answer you're after (no hard feelings, I really wouldn't want to be the guy fixing this).

Comment: I have no time to learn how to rewire my kitchen - could someone tell me how to do it with this screwdriver and plank of 2x4? ... that's essentially what your question boils down to.

Comment: Oh God ...! Actually it's a good thing all guys in here support each other on such situations. All give downvote, All say their advices, All give upvote to each other's advices. Anyway, I'm on a project and I have to finish it in 2 hours. So I really cannot start learing a DOM parser.

Comment: DOMDocument would take about 10 minutes, honestly, it's really easy - especially if you've done any DOM manipulation with JS in the past... I mean, what exactly are you trying to match with that RegExp? *Any* empty HTML element, just a handful of specific ones? Invalid code? A very specific pattern? What? Attempting to answer this, as is, would fall foul of the XY problem - so you're unlikely to get any good answers.

Comment: (not a downvoter) Here are good answers about [Why not parsing HTML with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: I know regex sometimes aren't the best solution, and people want/have to use them anyway. Not joining that discussion. But you could at least provide some example input strings, and their expected output. Failing that is worth a down-vote on it's own ;)

Comment: Is it something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/qpZk2J/3) you're after?

Comment: You really should use the proper parsing tools and stop trying to fudge a solution of your own that will ultimately never work properly.  That way madness lies.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly, this is how you *should* have phrased the question:**

> Within the following sample HTML data:
>
> ```
> <a href="profile/xalil">
>   <li>
>     <img src="../users/avatar/small/thumb_default.jpg" />
>     <p>xalil eshghi</p>
>     <span></span>
>   </li>
> </a>
> ```
>
> I want to find the value of the `href`, the `img src`, the `p`
>   contents and the `span` contents.
>
> I tried using the following regexp.........

---

Using a regular expression for this is, as you already know, [the wrong approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610). You *could* potentially "fix" your regex solution hack by replacing:

```
<s([^>]+)([^<]+)<\/span>
```

With:

```
<span>([^<]*)<\/span>
```

...However, not only is this still very difficult to read, but it doesn't account for all sorts of possible edge cases.

A few simple examples: What if the HTML is commented out, or it used single quotes, or the `img` tag contains another attribute before the `src`? You could also encounter far more critical issues due to your use of `[\s\S]+` in the pattern - which could potentially cause the regex to jump ahead to an entirely different section of HTML!

---

**This problem can, and should, easily be solved by using the DOM parser.** Something like this:

```
<?php
// This is just some boilerplate code for the sake of completion...
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("your_page.html");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

// Do you want to scope your results to within <ul class="users"> ?
// If not, just use: $links = $xpath->query("//a");
$links = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='users']/a");

// Guard clause
if (is_null($links)) { return; }

$result = array();
foreach ($links as $link) {
  $href = $link->getAttribute('href');      // PART 1 - Get the href
  $img = $xpath->query("li/img", $link)[0];
  $img_src = $img->getAttribute('src');     // PART 2 - Get the img src
  $p = $xpath->query("li/p", $link)[0];
  $p_text = $p->textContent;                // PART 3 - Get the p contents
  $span = $xpath->query("li/span", $link)[0];
  $span_text = $span->textContent;          // PART 4 - get the span contents
  $result[] = [$href, $img_src, $p_text, $span_text];
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

Solving the problem like this is not only much easier to read and maintain, but it accounts for all of the above mentioned potential bugs with your regex approach.

Answer (score 2):

This should help, I suppose. (Assuming the file you want analysed is the one you put in in your regex101, and the fields you want are the fields you were trying to extract in your regexp)

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("testfile.html");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query("//ul[@class='users']/a");
$result = array();
if (!is_null($links)) {
  foreach ($links as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    $img = $xpath->query("li/img", $link)[0];
    $img_src = $img->getAttribute('src');
    $p = $xpath->query("li/p", $link)[0];
    $p_text = $p->textContent;
    $span = $xpath->query("li/span", $link)[0];
    $span_text = $span->textContent;
    $result[] = [$href, $img_src, $p_text, $span_text];
  }
}
print_r($result);
```